# How to calculate medians using pandas with NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file I imported and I have with 59 columns. I want to calculate the medians in each column.

Each column has a mixture of NaN values and real integer values, as do the rows.

[image]

I have to keep all records as each row has a valid measurement in it and if I drop the NaN values by column or row my data set is empty.

I had set the NaN to zero but I could not get it to ignore the 0 values.

Currently I have the site number and one other corresponding measure and removing NaN values for each column as an independent unit but this is very time consuming.

Is there a better method to calculate median given data circumstances?

Comment: Please post that dataframe as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 12):

[**`pandas.DataFrame.median`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.median.html) ignores `NaN` by default, you have to explicitly change the **`skipna`** flag to `False` in order to include `NaN/null` values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,np.nan, 4,5], 'col2': [4,5,6,np.nan, np.nan,7]})

df.median()

col1    3.0
col2    5.5
dtype: float64

df.median(skipna=False)

col1   NaN
col2   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Just `df.median()` works :D, the default behavior is to ignore `NaN`

Comment: The code I ran earlier did not work, hence why I thought I needed to get rid of the NaN values (and based on the error message). I deleted the code that was not working earlier to try a new method that worked but took a lot longer. In future I will post what did not work.